# ActiveRecord with "references" keyword ignores columns in "select" part

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Option.includes(:yaoption).references(:yaoption).select('options.id, yaoptions.name').where(options: {dept_id: 100})
```

results in following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    options.id AS t0_r0,
    options.title AS t0_r1,
    options.dept_id AS t0_r2,
    options.mode AS t0_r3,
    options.content AS t0_r4,
    options.yaoption_id AS t0_r5,
    options.created_at AS t0_r6,
    options.updated_at AS t0_r7,
    yaoptions.id AS t1_r0,
    yaoptions.name AS t1_r1,
    options.id,
    yaoptions.name
FROM
    options
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yaoptions ON yaoptions.id = options.yaoption_id
WHERE
    options.dept_id = 100
ORDER BY
    options.id ASC
```

ActiveRecord query with `references` keyword seems to ignore the `select` part.

I would like to see just:

```
SELECT
    options.id,
    yaoptions.name
FROM
    options
    INNER JOIN yaoptions ON yaoptions.id = options.yaoption_id
WHERE
    options.dept_id = 100
```

When I use `joins` the right query is being sent:

```
Option.joins(:yaoption).select('options.id, yaoptions.name').where(options: {dept_id: 100})
```

but result contains only `id`s from `options` table:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Option id: 1>, #<Option id: 2>, #<Option id: 3>]>
```

I want a single query with specified fields only.

Answer (score 0):

Although `inspect` lists `Option` with `id` only, the `name` attribute is also accessible.